TransientObjectException when saving entity references in Hibernate
I’m facing a TransientObjectException when trying to create and persist an Activity entity that references a Methodology entity through an ActivityMethodology join table. Despite ensuring that the Methodology entity is found in the database and managed, I still encounter the following error when I attempt to persist the relationship:
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.unfccc.activityservice.entity.Methodology
The Entities
Here’s a simplified version of my entity relationships:
1.)Activity: Has many Methodology entities through a join table.
2.)Methodology: A simple entity that can exist independently and should be linked to activities.
3.)ActivityMethodology: A join table entity that connects Activity and Methodology with a composite key.
What I’ve Tried
Checking if Methodology is Managed: Before linking it to the Activity, I check if the Methodology already exists in the database and make sure it's managed by the EntityManager.
Persisting or Merging: Depending on whether the Methodology already exists, I either persist it or merge it to ensure it’s in a managed state.
Flushing and Refreshing: I’ve added explicit flush() and refresh() calls after persisting or merging, to ensure the state is synchronized with the database.
Despite this, I still get the TransientObjectException.
List<ActivityMethodology> activityMethodologies = new ArrayList<>();
if (activity.getMethodology() != null && !activity.getMethodology().isEmpty()) {
    for (Methodology methodology : activity.getMethodology()) {
        // Check if the Methodology already exists
        Methodology existingMethodology = methodologyService.findByMethodologyName(methodology.getMethodologyName());

        if (existingMethodology == null) {
            // Persist new Methodology
            log.info("Persisting new methodology...");
            entityManager.persist(methodology);
            entityManager.flush(); // Ensure it's saved in the DB
            existingMethodology = methodology;
        } else {
            log.info("Methodology is already managed.");
        }

        log.info("Methodology is now managed with ID: " + existingMethodology.getMethodologyId());

        // Create ActivityMethodology link
        ActivityMethodology activityMethodology = new ActivityMethodology();
        ActivityMethodologyId id = new ActivityMethodologyId(activity.getActivityNumber(), existingMethodology.getMethodologyId());
        activityMethodology.setId(id);
        activityMethodology.setActivity(activity);
        activityMethodology.setMethodology(existingMethodology);

        log.info("Persisting ActivityMethodology...");
        activityMethodologyService.saveActivityMethodology(activityMethodology);
    }
}

The Logs
Here’s the log showing the ID of the Methodology being retrieved correctly, but then the error
2024-10-24 14:08:38.043 INFO Existing methodology found with ID: d2fd8cbf-8af6-44d9-b349-1f75dc7f1e3c
2024-10-24 14:08:38.044 INFO Methodology is already managed.
2024-10-24 14:08:38.100 ERROR Error creating Activity
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: com.unfccc.activityservice.entity.Methodology
My Question
Why am I still getting a TransientObjectException even though I’m ensuring that Methodology is managed by the EntityManager?
How can I resolve this error and correctly persist the relationship between Activity and Methodology through ActivityMethodology?
Edit: 25/10/2024: This is the method where I save the activity
 /**
 * Saves or updates an activity.
 *
 * @param activity The activity to save or update.
 * @return The saved or updated activity.
 */
@Transactional
@Override
public Activity saveActivity(Activity activity) {
    return activityRepository.save(activity);
}


/**
 * Creates a new activity with associated entities and relationships.
 *
 * @param activityNumber The unique number identifying the activity.
 * @param activity       The activity object to be created.
 * @return               The created and persisted activity.
 */
@Override
public Activity createActivity(String activityNumber, Activity activity) {
    // Check if an activity with the given activityNumber already exists
    Activity existingActivityOpt = findByActivityNumber(activityNumber);
    if (existingActivityOpt != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity with number " + activityNumber + " already exists.");
    }

    // Validate that activityNumber is not null or empty
    if (activityNumber == null || activityNumber.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity number is required, cannot be null or empty.");
    }

    activity.setActivityNumber(activityNumber);

    // Initialize empty lists for related entities if they are null
    if (activity.getActivityHostParties() == null) {
        activity.setActivityHostParties(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    if (activity.getInvoices() == null) {
        activity.setInvoices(new ArrayList<>());
    }
    if (activity.getFocalPoints() == null) {
        activity.setFocalPoints(new ArrayList<>());
    }

    // Link CPAs (sub-activities) to the Activity
    if (!activity.getCpas().isEmpty()) {
        List<CPA> linkedCpas = new ArrayList<>();
        for (CPA cpa : activity.getCpas()) {
            CPA existingCpa = cpaService.findCPAByTitle(cpa.getTitle());
            if (existingCpa != null) {
                // If CPA exists, associate it with the current activity
                existingCpa.setActivity(activity);
                linkedCpas.add(existingCpa);
            } else {
                // Otherwise, create a new CPA linked to the activity
                cpa.setActivity(activity);
                linkedCpas.add(cpa);
            }
        }
        activity.setCpas(linkedCpas);
    }

    // Link Host Parties to the Activity
    if (!activity.getActivityHostParties().isEmpty()) {
        List<ActivityHostParty> linkedHostParties = new ArrayList<>();
        for (ActivityHostParty hostParty : activity.getActivityHostParties()) {
            ActivityHostParty existingHostParty = activityHostPartyService.findById(hostParty.getHostPartyId());
            if (existingHostParty != null) {
                linkedHostParties.add(existingHostParty);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid Host Party ID: " + hostParty.getHostPartyId());
            }
        }
        activity.setActivityHostParties(linkedHostParties);
    }

    // Link Methodologies to the Activity
    List<ActivityMethodology> activityMethodologies = new ArrayList<>();
    if (activity.getMethodology() != null && !activity.getMethodology().isEmpty()) {
        for (Methodology methodology : activity.getMethodology()) {
            // Check if the Methodology already exists by its name
            Methodology existingMethodology = methodologyService.findByMethodologyName(methodology.getMethodologyName());

            if (existingMethodology == null) {
existingMethodology = methodologyService.createMethodology(methodology);
                // Persist new Methodology if it does not exist
                entityManager.persist(methodology);
                entityManager.flush(); // Ensure it is saved in the DB immediately
                existingMethodology = methodology;
            }

            // Create link entity ActivityMethodology to associate Activity with Methodology
            ActivityMethodology activityMethodology = new ActivityMethodology();
            ActivityMethodologyId id = new ActivityMethodologyId(activity.getActivityNumber(), existingMethodology.getMethodologyId());
            activityMethodology.setId(id);
            activityMethodology.setActivity(activity);
            activityMethodology.setMethodology(existingMethodology);

            activityMethodologyService.saveActivityMethodology(activityMethodology);
            activityMethodologies.add(activityMethodology);
        }
    }

    // Set the methodologies list in the Activity entity
    activity.setMethodologies(activityMethodologies);

    // Save the complete Activity with all relationships and return it
    return this.saveActivity(activity);
}

Edit 28/10/2024 Entites:
Activity:
@Entity

@Table(name = "activities", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"activity_number"})
})
//@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "activityNumber")
public class Activity {

    // @Id
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    // @Column(name = "id")
    // private Long id; // Primary Key, auto-generated by the database

    @Id
    @Column(name = "activity_number")
    private String activityNumber; // Activity Number

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String activityTitle; // Activity Title

    @Column(name = "estimated_annual_average_greenhouse_gas")
    private BigDecimal estimatedAnnualAverageGreenhouseGas; // Estimated annual average greenhouse gas

    @Column(name = "pdd_document_reference")
    private String pddDocumentReference; // PDD Document Reference

    @Column(name = "activity_type")
    private String activityType; // Activity type (Possible values: "PoA", "Activity")

    @Column(name = "scale")
    private String scale; // Scale (Possible values: "Small", "Large")

    @Column(name = "host_party_approved_for_transition")
    private Boolean hostPartyApprovedForTransition; // Host Party Approved for Transition

    @Column(name = "crediting_type")
    private String creditingType; // Crediting Type (Possible values: "Renewable", "Fixed")

    @Column(name = "current_crediting_period")
    private Integer currentCreditingPeriod; // Current Crediting Period

    @Column(name = "current_crediting_period_start_date")
    private Date currentCreditingPeriodStartDate; // Current Crediting Period Start Date

    @Column(name = "current_crediting_period_end_date")
    private Date currentCreditingPeriodEndDate; // Current Crediting Period End Date

    @Column(name = "effective_crediting_period_end_date")
    private Date effectiveCreditingPeriodEndDate; // Effective Crediting Period End Date

    @Column(name = "page_link_to_cdm_is")
    private String pageLinkToCDMIS; // Page Link to CDM IS

    @Column(name = "doe_registration")
    private String doeRegistration; // DOE Registration

    @Column(name = "cdm_registration_date")
    private Date cdmRegistrationDate; // CDM Registration Date

    @Column(name = "deregistration_date")
    private Date deregistrationDate; // Deregistration Date

    @Column(name = "mis_methodology")
    private String misMethodology; // MIS Methodology (Date field)

    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state; // State of the project

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CPA> cpas = new ArrayList<>();
  
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    //@JsonManagedReference(value = "activity-hostParty")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("activity") 
    private List<ActivityHostParty> activityHostParties = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Invoice> invoices = new ArrayList<>();

   
@ManyToMany( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(
    name = "activity_focal_point",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "focal_point_id")
)
//@JsonBackReference(value = "focalPoint-activities")
    private List<FocalPoint> focalPoints;

    // @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    // @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id")
    // private List<Methodology> methodologies;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Scope> scopes = new ArrayList<>();

    // @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // @JoinTable(
    //     name = "activity_methodology", // Name der Zwischentabelle
    //     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id"), // Fremdschlüssel für Activity
    //     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "methodology_id") // Fremdschlüssel für Methodology
    // )
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Methodology> methodology  = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ActivityHostPartyAddendum> activityHostPartyAddendums = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<ActivityMethodology> methodologies = new ArrayList<>();;

Methodology
@Entity
@Table(name = "methodologies")


// , uniqueConstraints = {
//     @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"methodologyName"})
// })
public class Methodology {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "methodology_id")
    private UUID methodologyId;

    @Column(name = "methodology_name")
    private String methodologyName;

    @Column(name = "methodology_version")
    private String methodologyVersion;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status; // Possible values: "Active", "Inactive"

    // @OneToMany(mappedBy = "methodology", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    // private List<Activity> activities = new ArrayList<>();
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "methodology_scope",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "methodology_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "scope_id")
    )
    private List<Scope> scopes = new ArrayList<>();

    // One-to-Many relationship between Methodology and ActivityMethodology
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "methodology", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ActivityMethodology> activityMethodologies;

ActivityMethodology
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity_methodology")
public class ActivityMethodology {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ActivityMethodologyId id;

  
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "activity_number_key", referencedColumnName = "activity_number", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Activity activity;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "methodology_id_key", referencedColumnName = "methodology_id", insertable = true, updatable = true)
    private Methodology methodology;


Can you show the full code of the method where you save activity?

I have edited my post where you can see the save activity method

Can you show the entities Activity, Methodology and ActivityMethodology?

I’ve just uploaded the entities for Activity, Methodology, and ActivityMethodology. Thanks for taking a look

The problem is in your mapping.
@ElementCollection
private List<Methodology> methodology  = new ArrayList<>();

I think this particular error will go away if you clear its methodology field before saving the activity.
activity.setMethodology(null);
saveActivity(activity);

But this will not save you from further problems, so I offer you this mapping option.
@Entity
@Table(name = "activities")
public class Activity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "activities_methodologies",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name ="activity_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "methodology_id"))
    private Set<Methodology> methodologies;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "methodologies")
public class Methodology {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "methodologies")
    private Set<Activity> activities;
}

Then the procedure for saving activity will look something like this.
@Override
@Transactional
public Activity createActivity(Activity activity) {
    Set<Methodology> entities = new HashSet<>();
    for (Methodology methodology : activity.getMethodologies()) {
        Methodology entity = methodologyRepository.findByName(methodology.getName());
        if (entity == null) {
            entity = new Methodology();
            entity.setName(methodology.getName());
            methodologyRepository.save(entity);
        }
        entities.add(entity);
    }
    activity.setMethodologies(entities);
    return activityRepository.save(activity);
}

Here I am using Spring Data JPA
public interface ActivityRepository extends JpaRepository<Activity, Long> {
}

public interface MethodologyRepository extends JpaRepository<Methodology, Long> {

    Methodology findByName(String name);
}


Thank you for your help!
There’s actually no direct relationship between Activity and Methodology in my setup. The connection is only through an intermediate table, ActivityMethodology. The issue arises specifically when trying to associate an existing Methodology object from the database with an Activity again.
I’ll look into this further, but I appreciate your suggestion

@Jakob Re. "There’s actually no direct relationship between Activity and Methodology in my setup." In the mapping that I suggested to you, too.
